# Trino (Presto) raising PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR in cascade

Tags: presto, trino, hive-metastore

I'm constantly getting the **PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR** when running 30 queries in parallel (sometimes less, 10):

```
TrinoQueryError(type=INTERNAL_ERROR, name=PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR, message="Error fetching http://100.120.159.65:8080/v1/task/20220316_131644_00003_67ame.1.11.0/results/0/1: Expected response code to be 200, but was 503:
```

I got the same error previously, and on the occasion, the nodes were crashing due to system insufficient memory. The `jvm.maxHeapSize` was set high and low memory remained in the system processes.
The solution was setting the `jvm.maxHeapSize` to less than 80% of the *worker total memory*. And setting the max memory per worker as <90% of *instance total memory*.

Now I am not sure this is the case. I believe I followed the community/docs recommendations for JVM and query memory limits:

- My cluster has 20 nodes (r5a.8xlarge: 32 CPUS, 230 GB Mem)
- I limited the jvm.maxHeapSize=166G (<80% of instance total memory).
- The Heap Headroom is with the default of 30%*jvm.maxHeapSize.
- Query memory limits are: query.max-memory-per-node=40GB and query.max-memory=800GB
  (Other properties in the thread)

Also, my coordinator properties are set:

```
coordExtraParam: |
  protocol.v1.alternate-header-name=Presto
  http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
  http-server.process-forwarded=true
  query.client.timeout=45s
  task.http-response-threads=500
  query.max-concurrent-queries=50
  query.max-history=10000
  query.max-planning-time=2m
  query.max-execution-time=10m
  query.max-run-time=15m
  query.min-expire-age=30d
  query.max-memory-per-node=40GB
  query.max-memory=800GB
  task.concurrency=16
  task.max-drivers-per-task=3
  exchange.client-threads=25
  node-scheduler.max-splits-per-node=1024
  node-scheduler.max-pending-splits-per-task=6
  task.max-worker-threads=14
  node-scheduler.min-candidates=10
  optimizer.force-single-node-output=false
  query.low-memory-killer.policy=total-reservation-on-blocked-nodes
  spill-enabled=true
  spiller-spill-path=/tmp/spill
  spiller-max-used-space-threshold=0.9
  spiller-threads=4
  max-spill-per-node=100GB
  query-max-spill-per-node=100GB
  spill-compression-enabled=true
```

And I am using Hive Metastore:

```
connectors:
  hive.properties: |-
    connector.name=hive-hadoop2
    hive.metastore.uri=[redacted]
    hive.security=allow-all
    hive.storage-format=PARQUET
    hive.parquet.max-read-block-size=32MB
    hive.parquet.use-column-names=true
    hive.s3select-pushdown.enabled=true
    hive.s3.max-connections=10000
```

A single query generally runs finely, but when running queries in parallel (10, 20, 30), they do not perform so well or produce the error above.

I am trying to figure out the reason my cluster is failing down with those PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR. I will be thankful if someone has any comments to share about this case.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might suffer from https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/11234 that will be released in 374

Comment: Tested with version 374 (issue fix) but unfortunately didn't work